# Android click button to call boolean function to check if table exists

Tags: android, sqlite

I am completely stuck. been banging my head against a brick wall all day!

I have a class:

```
public class Main extends Activity.
```

This has several buttons. 
On 2 of the buttons I want to get the result of a boolean function that checks if a database table exists or not so that I can choose the next action.

```
final Button reminderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminders);

reminderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){

        //This is where I want to get the result from the boolean function
        // and then either provide a toast msg OR start a new activity
    }   
});
```

Below is the boolean function

```
public boolean isTableExists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
    if (tableName == null || db == null || !db.isOpen()) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = ? 
                         AND name = ?",new String[] { "table", tableName });
    if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        return false;
    }
    int count = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    return count > 0;
}
```

For the life of me I cannot work out the syntax to put in my onclick (View v){}

I had tried

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    isTableExists(null, null);
}
```

but I dont think the null,null is correct, but what arguments go in there?

or am I on the wrong track completely?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: I think that you do not know what you want ) YOu should pass database and table name to isTableExists to check them exist.

Answer (score 2):

From your post i understand that you want to `check whether Table exists or not`.

This code will help you.

```
public boolean isTableExists(String tableName, boolean openDb) {
    if(openDb) {
        if(mDatabase == null || !mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            mDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        }

        if(!mDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
            mDatabase.close();
            mDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        }
    }

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
                    cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Based on this boolean value You can do your action.